# Tinkerpop Gremlin Query: Find all edges pointing back to a vertex in the current path

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinnet

I query the following path:

`Company` has `Employees` has `User`

From `User` I want to find all `HasRights` edges which point back to the **current** `Company` (the user also has rights on other companies).

> See TODO in code below:

Gremlin Query:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("Company")
.project("Company","Employees")
// >>>> this is the company I want to filter by below
  .by(__.identity())
  .by(__.out("Has").hasLabel("Employee").not(__.has("IsDeleted",true)).has("Status",neq(5).and(neq(4)))
  .project("Employee","User","Rights")
    .by(__.identity())
    .by(__.out("Has").hasLabel("User"))
    .by(__.out("Has").hasLabel("User").outE("HasRight")
// >>>> TODO here I need to filter by above company
      .where(__.inV().hasLabel("Company")))
  .fold())
.fold())
```

Comment: Is the question about how to express the query correctly using GremlinQ or is it just about how to write the query in Gremlin first (before converting it to a form suitable for GremlinQ) ?

Comment: it's about how to write the query in Gremlin first (before converting it to a form suitable for GremlinQ)

Comment: Could you please add the Gremlin query you currently have to the question to make it easier to understand for people not familiar with GremlinQ syntax? That would be very helpful if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying things a little, just to make the example smaller, in cases like this you should be able to use this pattern:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Company').as('c').
      out('Has').hasLabel('Employee').
      out('Has').hasLabel('User').
      outE('HasRight).where(inV().as('c'))
```

Comment: super, thank you!